# undefined is not a function near var lightbox = new Lightbox({

Tags: jquery, magento, undefined, lightbox

```
function initLightbox(){
   var lightbox =  new Lightbox({
        fileLoadingImage:'/images/loading.gif',
        fileBottomNavCloseImage: '/images/closelabel.gif',
        overlayOpacity: 0.8,   
        animate: true,         
        resizeSpeed: 7,        
        borderSize: 10,
        labelImage: "Image",
        labelOf: "of"
    });
}
if (Prototype.Browser.IE) {
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){ 
        initLightbox();
    });
}
```

It shows `undefined` is not a function near  `"var lightbox =  new Lightbox({"..` .Please help me where I am wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that:

- you included lightbox script
- lightbox script URL is correct and visible online
- you don't have some errors before the ones you point out
- seen that you are working on Magento & Prototype, that jquery works properly in addiction to Prototype

Comment: Yes i was using Magento and there was a conflict with prototype js. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you didn't include the lightbox script and, if you did, the path to it is wrong.